# Python eggs and module as plugin

Tags: python, plugins, egg

I have these eggs:

```
~/test/lib/
├── a-1.0-py2.7.egg
│   ├── a
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   └── EGG-INFO
│       └── ...
├── a.b-1.0-py2.7.egg
│   ├── a
│   │   └── b
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── __init__.pyc
│   └── EGG-INFO
│       └── ...
├── easy-install.pth
├── site.py
└── site.pyc
```

a/__init__.py is:

```
print "a"
```

a/b/__init__.py is:

```
print "a.b"
```

So, "a.b" is a "plugin" for "a". I would install it separately (as most others).
But in that configuration my idea doesn't work:

```
>>> import a
a
>>> import a.b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named b
>>>
```

How it must be?

Answer (score 0):

check your generated egg-file, if there is a module a.b.

If not, try do use find_packages to register your modules.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name='pypack',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    ...
```

```
├── a.b-1.0-py2.7.egg
│   ├── a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.pyc
│   │   └── b
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── __init__.pyc
│   └── EGG-INFO
│       └── ...
```

each folder should have an

```
__init__.py
```

Comment: No. This doesn't work, because python searching for "b" module inside of "a". It doesn't try importing "a.b" egg, just "a".
And yes, inside "a.b" egg folder "a" haven't \_\_init\_\_.py file. It does not matter.